# How to make camera follow object with tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I made a player prefab with a tag **Player** that is spawned in the scene when the game starts.How can I make the camera follow the player using the **Player** tag.

Currently using the following script

```
    public Transform target;            // The position that that camera will be following.
    public float smoothing = 5f;        // The speed with which the camera will be following.

    Vector3 offset;                     // The initial offset from the target.


    void Start ()
    {
        // Calculate the initial offset.
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }


    void FixedUpdate ()
    {

        // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
        Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

        // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

As

```
public Transform target;            // The position that that camera will be following.
public float smoothing = 5f;        // The speed with which the camera will be following.


Vector3 offset;                     // The initial offset from the target.


void Start()
{
    try
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform; // this is goint to find a certain tagged object from hirarchey and assing it to target.
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("target gameObjects is not present in hierarchy ");
    }

    // Calculate the initial offset.
    offset = transform.position - target.position;
}


void FixedUpdate()
{

    // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
    Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

    // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

or You can make a event and find gameObejct with tag when it spawned at certain time

As

```
public Transform target;            // The position that that camera will be following.
public float smoothing = 5f;        // The speed with which the camera will be following.


Vector3 offset;                     // The initial offset from the target.


void Start()
{
    // Calculate the initial offset.

    offset = transform.position - target.position;
}

// Call this method where you spawing your target and set the tag and call this mehtod supply tag parameter 
public void FindTaggedGameObject(string tag)
{
    try
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform; // this is goint to find a certain tagged object from hirarchey and assing it to target.
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("target gameObjects is not present in hierarchy ");
    }
}


void FixedUpdate()
{

    // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
    Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

    // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: gave an error **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CompleteProject.CameraFollow.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/_CompletedAssets/Scripts/Camera/CameraFollow.cs:27)**

Comment: which one gave error Which one you have tried ?  have you add the tag to the target object ? when do your object spawn ? if it is in start make it spawn at awake

Comment: It will be null if target doesnt exist. Do if(target != null) { }

Comment: @VedSarkar if this answer was help to you please accpet it as correct answer by pressing the tick thanks

Comment: @SyedAnwarFahim had to modify the code a bit. link to the code goo.gl/lGqynR